# After inserting a new OS entry, GRUB2 asks for password

Tags: boot, grub2, password, android

Yesterday I installed a new fresh Ubuntu system, and installed Android-x86 in another partition. Then I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481982/add-android-x86-4-4-rc2-to-ubuntu-grub) tutorial to add an entry for Android-x86. My 40_custom file:

```
#! /bin/sh -e

cat << EOF

menuentry "Android-x86 r1" {
    set root='(hd0,6)'
    linux /android-4.4-r1/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-4.4-r1
    initrd /android-4.4-r1/initrd.img
}
EOF
```

When I ran `update-grub` command everything went fine, and the entry has been created successfully. But when I rebooted the system and tried to access my Android-x86, grub2 asked for an user and password. I never set any user neither password for my grub2, and not even asked it to protect my Android-x86 menuentry. What is the problem here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: grub might be broken. You can follow the instructions [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) to repair it or reinstall it.

In a nutshell:

- you boot from a live (in this case ubuntu) cd/usb
- mount the partition where grub is installed (See the **EDIT**...)
- bind the directories that grub needs access to to detect other operating systems
- install, check, and update grub

---

**EDIT**: the link is dead, so here I provide the steps needed:

To mount the partition where GRUB is installed, you have to:
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt

sdX is the drive, and sdXY is the partition where GRUB is/was install(ed).

Once mounted, to bind the directories grubs, needs you have to:
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

And then, we chroot with:

sudo chroot /mnt

Install, check, and update grub with (you just need to provide the dirve letter, and not the partition. eg. /dev/sda and NOT /dev/sda2):

grub-install /dev/sdX, grub-install –recheck /dev/sdX.

grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX

Exit the chrooted system and unmount everything:

exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt

---

Somewhat longer answer:

I have being trying to install 8 different operating systems (win7 + 7 different GNU/Linux distros) in an old lap top and I have run into all kinds of problems with the install process and the way grub behaves. Yesterday It started asking for username/password in all but one grub entry (it was working fine before that). After following the instructions in the link, everything was back to normal.

Try installing Android and just running `update-grub` to let grub find the new kernel and update the menu.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using grub customizer? https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer

Try backing up your current custom settings, then remove them.  Install grub customizer and see if it detects your android install.  It worked for me when updating grub didn't detect an os I had installed on an external drive.

Comment: I first tried with GRUB Customizer, and it didn't work. So I tried using the aforementioned tutorial.