# Adding Ubuntu Minimum through grub2

Tags: unity, 16.04, grub2, android, mir

So few days ago, [I found the I could add folders in the system, add them through grub2 and boot it from there.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481982/add-android-x86-4-4-rc2-to-ubuntu-grub)
I kinda want to do the same thing as my system is in a GPT format and mini currently does not support UEFI boot and all. So what kind of modification I should do to add it to grub2?
Can I get some help on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the '/etc/grub.d/40_custom' script with the help of text editor as root.

Add this in the file:

menuentry “Ubuntu 14.04 ISO” 
{
set isofile=”/home/name/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso”
loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${isofile} quiet splash
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

Then 'sudo update-grub'

Remember to use the correct path and name of the iso. Now select the iso from the grub boot menu.

Also, It's always best to backup the 40_custom script to a separate location, just in case you need to restore it.

Sorry for the ill formatted response, typing from phone.

I have no access to a computer for sometime. Please bear with me. Requesting my peers here for an edit please.

Comment: Thanks for the response! One more thing though: How can I add persistence here?

Comment: No idea @JohnHyde